# BaseRepository Query Entity List Return List of Object Array

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA framework with Implementation of Hibernate.
I declared a query in A BaseRepository like below:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {
    @Query("select e.id,e.name from #{#entityName} e where e.state=1 and e.name like CONCAT(:name,'%')")
    List<T> findIdAndNameByNameStartingWith(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

And use in a Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/list/byName")
    public HttpApiResponse findAllByNameLike(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "") String name) {
        List<Platform> platforms = platformRepository.findIdAndNameByNameStartingWith(name);
        return HttpApiResponse.doSuccess(platforms);
    }
```

But When i Debug I found `findIdAndNameByNameStartingWith()` return List like [['hotel',1],['travel',2]] rather than `List<Platform>`. Could anyone give me some advice many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It returns what you ask

`select e.id,e.name from #{#entityName} e where e.state=1 and e.name like CONCAT(:name,'%')`

try to change to

`select e from #{#entityName} e where e.state=1 and e.name like CONCAT(:name,'%')`

Comment: Changing Query to `select e from...` may works but i don't want jpa to retrieve all fields in that table because this interface is invoked most frequently and some column stores big data.